# What does "best placed to achieve" mean?

Tags: sentence-construction

> If the USA has become a nation of interest groups, it is the very
> task of politics to blend divergent interests into great governing
> coalitions. **This, in Cronin’s view, parliament is best placed to
> achieve.**
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

I have a question about the sentence I emphasized. I interpret that sentence like this: "Parliament is best placed to achieve this".

But I think this sentence may have two meanings in my opinion:

> 1. Parliament have the best position to achieve this. (So it is the
>    parliament who achieves)

> 2. The parliament is best place for achieving this. (So someone
>    achieve this **in** parliament)

Which one is right?

Comment: Put an additional empty line right after `Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder`, so that the quote and your sentences don't get smushed together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best placed" is another idiomatic way of saying "in the best position".

A position, or placing, can be figurative - not a literal location in which someone or something is placed, but a set of circumstances.

In your excerpt, Cronin is saying that parliament is in the right position, or the right set of circumstances, to achieve the task of "blend[ing] divergent interests into great governing coalitions".